# Нету always on top в Manjaro Linux Xfce

Tags: linux, manjaro, xfce

Нету **always on top** в приложении **War Thunder**
открываю на одном мониторе игру на втором браузер **Mozilla**,
если нажать на браузер то игра сворачивается, хоть она и на втором мониторе.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.